# send text and emoji from android to php?

Tags: php, android, mysql, emoji

I tried to send text + emoji of android to another android throught php, in php I wrote the code to insert into mysql, everything work well but when it entered into table, the result change tobe question mark "??"
I've tried to find tutorials about this but I cant try it in my application

I tried to send a text + emoji using json array.

I use this code in java to send to php

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response;
try{
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    List<NameValuePair> nVP = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
    nVP.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mydata", paketan.toString()));  //studentJson is the JSON input
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nVP,"UTF-8"));
    response = client.execute(post);
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    hsl = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

this log in eclipse.

```
[{"Time": "2015-07-09 14:21:17", "msg": "test emoji  and "}]
```

here code in php.

```
$db->exec("SET NAMES ’utf8mb4’ COLLATE ’utf8mb4_unicode_ci’;");
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes(str_replace('\"', '"', $_POST["mydata"])));
```

and when the data is sent to php changed to "?"

```
[{"Time": "2015-07-09 14:21:17", "msg": "test emoji ? And ?"}]
```

I want to save it like the original data not question mark, how to solve this?

Comment: Make sure the table's collation is also utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: Have you checked exactly what is the character code for ?

Comment: @Vatev : my table was set utf8mb4_unicode_ci but still not work properly

Comment: @haike00 yes i have, are you mean like http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Comment: This is probably unrelated, but what is the purpose of `stripslashes(str_replace('\"', '"', $_POST["mydata"]))` ?

Comment: just to remove special char like ", but i've tried to remove stripslashes and resutl still the same..for information i've also try insert emoji from sql statement in phpmyadmin directly,and when i execute the sqlstatement the result is still question mark.

Comment: i think my problem in mysql, I follow this link https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4 but still unsuccess.

Comment: Make sure the problem isn't in phpmyadmin. It is possible that the value in the DB is correct, but its just displayed incorrectly in your debug tools.

Comment: yup,, in mysql i see question mark in column, but when i load use php the emoji display correctly..

Comment: so, this my purpose,, i make chat app in android follow this step, first android1 send text+emoji to android2, before the data is sent to android2,the data is processed in php, in php there is input process to table, after the data insert to table,then data reapers and packed to json and then sent to android2, in my android2 only received a question mark.

Comment: After reading your comments, the "problem" that you are facing is you can't get the emoji display properly on some media (eg. web browser) but not "I want to save it like the original data not question mark". The data is (most likely) "properly saved", the problem is you haven't tell exactly how you want to consume the data when putting it to the screen.

Comment: oh, my problem solved, my fault is i try it with 2 device, first device use my new version of app and my second device use older version of app.huh..